# When a file path longer than 100 characters is passed, crontab throws an error saying "No such file or directory"

Tags: debian, cron

```
$ touch aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBB
$ crontab aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBBB
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: No such file or directory
```

This behavior seems quite unusual (noticing how it also truncates the path in the error message). I'm using Debian bullseye 11.

Is this a bug, or is there a specific reason why crontab has such a peculiar limitation?

I'm not able to replicate it on the docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/crontab

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The version of `crontab` from Cygwin prints an explanatory error message:

```
file=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcd
touch "$file"
crontab "$file"
crontab: usage error: filename too long

echo "$file" | awk '{print length}'
108
```

The message addresses your concern, albeit without providing an explanation.

Unfortunately the version on Debian doesn't explain well:

```
crontab "$file"
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU: No such file or directory

echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU' | awk '{print length}'
99
```

However, the source code (`apt-get source crontab`) gives a massive clue in `cron.h`:

```
#define  MAX_FNAME       100     /* max length of internally generated fn */
```

And then in `crontab.c`:

```
static  char            Filename[MAX_FNAME];
…
(void) strncpy (Filename, argv[optind], (sizeof Filename)-1);
Filename[(sizeof Filename)-1] = '\0';
```

In case it's not obvious from these snippets, there's a hard-coded 99 character limit on the length of the filename. I can't see a reason for this other than an arbitrary "*that should be long enough*". The proper approach would probably have been to use [`PATH_MAX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)`+1`, but the author(s) didn't do that. A [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750409/when-a-file-path-longer-than-100-characters-is-passed-crontab-throws-an-error-s/750419#comment1427656_750419) notes that the code could have been written as early as 1988 (or as late as 1994), but quite possibly pre-POSIX where this constant was formalised.

Comment: Is there is a reason for this limit?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I didn't write the code, but it looks like it's a completely arbitrary "that should be long enough". The proper approach would probably have been to use `PATH_MAX`, but the author(s) didn't do that

Comment: This has been unchanged by Debian since 1999 when Paul Vixie's cron project was retrieved by Debian: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/blame/master/cron.h#L67 .  The value might have been set as early as 1988 (or as late as 1994).

Comment: @A.B so preceding POSIX by some margin. That would make sense, yes, thank you

Comment: @roaima `PATH_MAX` is also just an arbitrary value: https://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/pathmax-simply-isnt.html. But at least it is much longer than this `MAX_FNAME` here.

Comment: Good find. I'll send them a PR